# XCUITest doesn't find element on page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, voiceover, xcuitest

Certain elements are not "visible" in XCUITest, can't assert for them, their never found.
Even when I print `XCUIApplication()` from debugging the elements won't show.

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if you set the

```
isAccessbilityElement = true
```

property (which I did to support voice over) then all of the marked view's subviews will be hidden in XCUITest world.
My solution was to check if I'm running UITests, if so then set `false` to this flag if not, then `true`.

```
let application = XCUIApplication()
application.launchArguments = ["UITest"]
application.launch()

public var isRunningUITests: Bool {
    return arguments.contains("UITest")
}
```